# How to Merge Quote Items

Tags: magento-enterprise, cart, quote, ee-1.12

I'm trying to merge like items in the cart by taking the total quantity of an item by SKU (the ID field is unreliable as multiple items may return as empty/null), setting the first instance to the total quantity, then either deleting or changing the rest to 0. This doesn't seem to work, however. This runs in an observer for the events `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `checkout_cart_product_update_after`.

**Edit:** Brought in the code from `removeItem()` directly since it only works by ID, which may sometimes be blank. Now I'm unable to add items to the cart *at all*.

```
$version = floatval(Mage::getVersion());
$quantities = array();

foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if(!array_key_exists($item->getSku(),$quantities))
        { $quantities[$item->getSku()] = $item->getQty(); }
    else {
        $quantities[$item->getSku()] += $item->getQty();

        if($version >= 1.13)
            { $quote->deleteItem($item); }
        else {
            $item->isDeleted(true);
            if($item->getHasChildren()) {
                foreach($item->getChildren() as $child)
                    { $child->isDeleted(true); }
            }
            $parent = $item->getParentItem();
            if($parent)
                { $parent->isDeleted(true); }
            Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_remove_item',array('quote_item'=>$item));
        }
    }
}

$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The function `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::removeItem()` expects `$itemId` as a parameter, not an `$item` object.

So, your first `foreach` statement should be:

```
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if(!array_key_exists($item->getSku(),$quantities))
        { $quantities[$item->getSku()] = $item->getQty(); }
    else {
        $quantities[$item->getSku()] += $item->getQty();
        $quote->removeItem($item->getId());
    }
}
```

---

This function is available in Enterprise 1.13. It gives the option to delete a quote item that doesn't have an id:

```
public function deleteItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
{
    if ($item->getId()) {
        $this->removeItem($item->getId());
    } else {
        $quoteItems = $this->getItemsCollection();
        $items = array($item);
        if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
            foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                $items[] = $child;
            }
        }
        foreach ($quoteItems as $key => $quoteItem) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($quoteItem->compare($item)) {
                    $quoteItems->removeItemByKey($key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: What if some of the items have an empty or null ID?

Comment: You could try this function `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::deleteItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)`. This is the comment that goes with it "Delete quote item. If it does not have identifier then it will be only removed from collection". That might do the trick.

Comment: Used it and the server got stuck in a loop. Checked out the method and it doesn't exist. For the time being I'm just using the raw code from `removeItem()` as it pertains to a cached quote item.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that function is new in magento 1.13. I've added the code of that function to my answer. Hopefully it'll help you or give you some inspiration to solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to permit *anything* to be added to the cart now instead of just merging duplicates.